# Taking zeroth cohomology of a dg-module over a dg-category is "good" on representables, but probably "bad" on cones

Tags: ct.category-theory, dg-categories

This question is possibly related to [this other one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/176507/good-properties-of-the-h0-functor-from-quasi-functors-to-ordinary-functors).

Let $\mathcal A$ be a dg-category over a commutative ring $k$. I denote by $\text{dgm-}\mathcal A$ the dg-category of right dg-$\mathcal A$-modules, that is, dg-functors
\begin{equation}
\mathcal A^{\text{op}} \to \mathbf C_{\text{dg}}(k),
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf C_{\text{dg}}(k)$ is the dg-category of cochain complexes of $k$-modules. In general, the category of dg-functors $\mathrm{Fun}_{\text{dg}}(\mathcal A, \mathcal B)$ between two dg-categories is itself a dg-category, with hom-complexes denoted by $\mathrm{Nat}_{\text{dg}}(F,G)$ (the complex of natural transformations $F \to G$).

Let me recall the (differential graded) Yoneda lemma. Given $F \in \text{dgm-}\mathcal A$, we have a natural isomorphism of complexes:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Nat}_{\text{dg}}(\mathcal A(-,A),F) \cong F(A).
\end{equation}
We also have the differential graded Yoneda embedding:
\begin{align}
h_{-} : \mathcal A \hookrightarrow \text{dgm-}\mathcal A, \\
A \mapsto \mathcal A(-,A).
\end{align}

A useful operation on dg-modules is taking cohomology. In fact, there is a functor
\begin{equation}
H^0(-) : H^0(\text{dgm-}\mathcal A) \to \text{mod-}H^0(\mathcal A),
\end{equation}
which takes a dg-module $F$ to the $H^0(\mathcal A)$-module of its zeroth cohomology.

Now, notice that the zeroth cohomology of a representable module $\mathcal A(-,A)$ is given by $H^0(\mathcal A(-,A)) = H^0(\mathcal A)(-,A)$. So, this $H^0(\mathcal A)$-module is also represented by $A$. Then, we can apply both the differential graded and the ordinary version of Yoneda lemma:
\begin{align}
& H^0(\mathrm{Nat}_{\text{dg}}(\mathcal A(-,A),F))  \cong H^0(F(A)) \\
&= H^0(F)(A) \cong \mathrm{Nat}(H^0(\mathcal A(-,A)), H^0(F)),
\end{align}
and it is immediate to see that this chain of maps gives actually the functorial map
\begin{equation}
H^0(\mathrm{Nat}_{\text{dg}}(\mathcal A(-,A),F)) \to \mathrm{Nat}(H^0(\mathcal A(-,A)), H^0(F))
\end{equation}
given by the above $H^0(-)$ functor. So, we have proven that in this case, this natural map is an isomorphism.

Now, let me take another step. I start from a closed degree zero map $f: A \to B$ in $\mathcal A$, which corresponds to a closed degree zero morphism $h_f : h_A \to h_B$ via the Yoneda embedding. The category $\text{dgm-}\mathcal A$ is (strongly) pretriangulated, so we can take the cone $C(h_f)$, which fits in the following pretriangle:
\begin{equation}
h_A \xrightarrow{h_f} h_B \to C(h_f) \to h_A[1].
\end{equation}
Now, let $F \in \text{dgm-}\mathcal A$, and consider the dg-functor
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Nat}_{\text{dg}}(-, F) : (\text{dgm-}\mathcal A)^{\text{op}} \to \mathbf{C}_{\text{dg}}(k).
\end{equation}
As a dg-functor, it maps pretriangles to pretriangles (caveat: because of contravariance, the sign of the shift is changed to the opposite). Hence, we obtain a pretriangle in $\mathbf{C}_{\text{dg}}(k)$:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Nat}_{\text{dg}}(h_B,F) \to \mathrm{Nat}_{\text{dg}}(h_A,F) \to \mathrm{Nat}_{\text{dg}}(C(h_f)[-1],F) \to \mathrm{Nat}_{\text{dg}}(h_B[-1],F).
\end{equation}
Moreover, Yoneda lemma gives a commutative square:

[image]
<sub>(source: [presheaf.com](http://presheaf.com/cache/d2s49263de4u5g636i316x5363r3k4s.png))</sub>
,

so we obtain a (functorial and strict!) isomorphism between cones:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Nat}_{\text{dg}}(C(h_f)[-1],F) \cong C(F(f))
\end{equation}
as cochain complexes. Rearranging shifts, we obtain:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Nat}_{\text{dg}}(C(h_f),F) \cong C(F(f))[-1].
\end{equation}
Now, I'd like to compare $H^0(\mathrm{Nat}_{\text{dg}}(C(h_f),F)) \cong H^0(C(F(f))[-1])$ with $\mathrm{Nat}(H^0(C(h_f)),H^0(F))$. Is it true or false that the natural map
\begin{equation*}
H^0(\mathrm{Nat}_{\text{dg}}(C(h_f),F)) \to \mathrm{Nat}(H^0(C(h_f)),H^0(F))
\end{equation*}
is an isomorphism? I expect the answer to be *no*, because, roughly speaking, taking cohomology "destroys" the functoriality of cones. How can I find a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take your DG-category to be a plain ring $R$, or the category of f.g. projective $R$-modules. Then you're asking the following question: Given a complex of f.g. projective $R$-modules $C$ concentrated in degrees $-1$ and $0$ and an arbitrary complex $F$, is $H^0(\hom(C,F))\cong \hom(H^0(C),H^0(F))$? Actually you're asking whether a specific map is an isomorphism, but I'll show you an example where there is no even an abstract isomorphism. Assume that the projective dimension of $R$ is $>0$ (otherwise your map is indeed an iso). Take two $R$-modules $M$ and $N$, $M$ finitely presented, such that $\operatorname{Ext}_R^1(M,N)\neq 0$. Let $C$ be a presentation of $M$ and $F=N[-1]$, in particular $H^0(F)=0$. However $H^0(\hom(C,F))$ surjects onto $\operatorname{Ext}_R^1(M,N)$, so it cannot be trivial.

Comment: Thanks! What about if I require $\mathcal A$ to be a dg-category over a *field*?

Comment: Take $R$ to be a $k$-algebra...